# How to submit a value from a PHP defined table to a php page for further processing?

Tags: php, html

I am using a form to submit data to a php page and then presenting it as a table using the  method which is working fine for me.  Now I want to submit one of the data field ($row->id) to another php page for processing detailed user profile.  I tried using the form method as shown in the code but it doesn't work and keeps submitting same value for every profile.

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $n++; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $lang[$row->gender]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->age; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->height; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->edn; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $lang[$row->income]; ?></td>
    <td><form action= 'compact.php' method='post'>
    <input type ='hidden' name='pid' value="<?php echo $row->id?>">
          <input type='submit' name='submit' value='View Details'></td>
 </tr>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use a simple $_GET query : `<a href="compact.php?pid=<?php echo $row->id?>">View details</a>` ?

Comment: Can you please show us a sample _output_ from the generated HTML table? 3 rows would be good.

Comment: @ Vincent Decaux Thanks for the help.  The Get query worked perfectly fine. Regards

Comment: There should be no reason why your original method doesn't work as far as I can see. But the href is simpler and fine for this case, I agree

Comment: If that's the _only_ thing you changed, then was it that your processing script was expecting a GET request instead of a POST request?

Comment: @ waterloomatt  Yes I think GET works better in this kind of situation.  Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on suggestions in the comments to above question, I changed my script as follows and used GET instead of POST at compact.php and was able to successfully capture the posted variable for further processing:

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $n++; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $lang[$row->gender]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->age; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->height; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->edn; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $lang[$row->income]; ?></td>
    <td><a href="compact.php?pid=<?php echo $row->id?>">
View details</a></td>
 </tr>
```